How to delete all manifests except with tags
I want to delete tall manifests in acr except the images with tags

Deleting manually with acr command is tedious and time taking
I was using this command for deleting with sha one by one
az acr manifest delete -r testqacontainers -n org/ip-tubelas@sha256:2erereiru8hdfhs704835a0712e8a1ab6d4c2d899e10d1370d3e

https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/105
This link helped me

Deleting manifests for images withtout images
Foreach($x in (az acr repository show-manifests -n testimggw --repository org/cloud-s3 | ConvertFrom-Json)) { if (!$x.tags) { az acr repository delete -n testimggw --image "org/cloud-s3@$($x.digest)" -y }}

Able to delete the images with the below script
Foreach($x in (az acr repository show-manifests -n testimggw --repository org/cloud-s3 | ConvertFrom-Json)) { if (!$x.tags) { az acr repository delete -n testimggw --image "org/cloud-s3@$($x.digest)" -y }}```

